# Dockerfile issue with Node.js application

Tags: docker

I am unable to build an application. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.io/node:16-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY ./ /usr/app
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
```

Error message:

```
npm ERR! path /usr/app
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! signal SIGKILL
npm ERR! command sh -c -- ng build
```

Comment: You want to use multistage build,you need from builder.

Comment: Probably, something wrong with npm run build stage. Please provide with full dockerfile, package.json and more logs